# HTML, table colspan issue

Tags: html

I want my email, password etc to be the same width as Name and Surname Together but I am struggling to this.

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="emer" placeholder="Emri"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mbiemer" placeholder="Mbiemri"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Emaili"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="email" placeholder="Password-i"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="email" placeholder="Rivendos Password-in"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

The `input` elements width needs to be set to `100%` to take the width of the container!

```css
td > input{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="emer" placeholder="Emri"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mbiemer" placeholder="Mbiemri"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Emaili"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="email" placeholder="Password-i"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="email" placeholder="Rivendos Password-in"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```